# Execute jQuery function on hover/mouseover certain area of div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-events

I have a nested div which is overflowing with text (`overflow: auto`). The parent div has the (`overflow: hidden`), and with this trick I am able to scroll using absolute positioning with a negative right offset. The two divs are on the right half of my webpage in a centered container.

I want to implement a scrolling system for these nested divs using hover. When the user hovers the lower 25% (red portion) of the nested divs, the content scrolls down. When the user hovers the upper 25% (blue portion) of the divs, the content scrolls up.

I've been having difficulty figuring out the best way to implement this. I tried using z-index and absolute positioning to stack divs with the correct % proportions behind the divs but I can't get jQuery to recognize that it's hovering over those divs because they are behind the content. The screenshot below shows the right hand side of my webpage.

http://i60.tinypic.com/2qw28vp.png

Is there a way to do this similar to image mapping, specifying an "area" of the div to trigger an event like text-scrolling on hover?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle to replicate the issue you're having. it seems like an issue that needs hands on knowledge to debug versus hypothetical/theoretical

Comment: why would you put them behind the divs? just move them to the front... and set background: transparent so you can see through them

Comment: Won't let me edit my first comment...but if you need to detect a click of an element behind another element, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/13jLrarp/1/

Comment: @JoeSager I had to put them behind (just for proportion purposes) because if they were in front I wouldn't be able to interact with the nested divs to scroll the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid creating empty divs on top of your text and instead listen to the jQuery's `mousemove` event and detect the `clientY` mouse position.

```
$('.container').mousemove(function (e) {
    if (e.clientY < $('.container').height() / 2) {
        scrollText('up')
    } else {
        scrollText('down')
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3hj9vfcr/